# How to enable View as a Web Page in FTAF content?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am creating a new Email campaign with ET Email Studio and when testing, I see that when doing FTAF, everything is correct except the View as a Web Page link that is present but not working. I understand that "Update profile" and "Unsubscribe" links must be disabled because the email content has been delivered to a friend that is not yet registered, but VAWP functionality should be enabled by default and the reality is that is also disabled.

How can I enable VAWP link in FTAF email content ? Thanks !